# barras de navegação do safari não desaparecem

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

Vou explicar isto pelo meio de prints

basicamente, existe estas barras do safari de navegação/endereço

http://prntscr.com/8mgtda
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ora, ao fazer scroll (quem usa um iphone, pode ver, encolhe a barra de navegação e as opções do safari desaparecem, podem ver do exemplo da www.apple.com ou do maisfutebol).

Agora, eu estou a fazer um site, em que sempre que faço scroll, faça o mesmo comportamento, seja em que browser for.

O que não acontece.

vou mostrar o que tenho http://prntscr.com/8mguji tenho um footer fixed, mas sinceramente, não acho que seja esse o problema, porque o maisfutebol também tem um parecido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já mudei a meta tag também, e não me resolveu o problema.

O mesmo fiz em javascript usando este código abaixo e nada fez também

```
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
```

Portanto alguém sabe a solução para este problema com os browsers?

Comment: RESOLVIDO: Ter cuidado com o overflow-x não pode estar hidden

Comment: rsrs, ia sugerir isso agora. Coloque isso como sua resposta para verem como você resolveu o seu problema.